# Will class variable reset to initial value on its own in python?

Tags: python-3.x, oop, python-3.7

Will class variable ever reset on its own when instance for that particular class is still present? 
I have a class and during instantiating an object, I update class variable within init for future use where I would not have access to the instantiated object. I know for a fact that the object is no out of scope when I try to access this class variable. Sample snippet is given below.

```
Class A:
    var = ""
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        A.var     = name
A_obj = A("John")
```

I want to use var (which is "John") at a later part. when I get to that part, value of "A.var"  is "" and not "John" as I expected The complete code is complicated to be posted here. So I have just provided basic scenario of what is happening

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what "reset" means to you, and if possible provide code or at least describe in detail what is happening?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver Done

Answer (score 0):

No.

Rather than a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would let us reproduce the symptom you see, you chose to provide code which works as documented and never shows the symptom, leaving us to guess about your situation. I enclose my guess, a slightly longer version of your code:

```
def empty():
    print('empty')
    return ''


class A:
    var = empty()
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        A.var     = name


obj_john = A('John')
print(A.var)

obj_mary = A('Mary')
print(A.var)
```

The big difference is logging of the empty string assignment, which seems to be your chief concern. Unsurprisingly, the output produced is:

```
empty
John
Mary
```

That is, the empty string was assigned exactly once, and then the ctor repeatedly overwrote the singleton.

If you abuse repeated `import`s of your module then you *might* manage to invoke the empty assignment twice, but you haven't described any of those interactions. Setting a debugger watchpoint might prove useful. Dig a bit further, and share with us what you found.